# PHP fgets reading wrong chunk size

Tags: php, fgets

I am trying to read chunks of specific length from an mp4 file:

```
$fp = fopen('file.mp4', 'rb');
$line = fgets($fp, 204800);
echo strlen($line);
```

I suppose it should output 204800 but it only prints 1547. Any idea what is wrong here?

Comment: @DaveChen yes, still wrong size :(

Answer (score 4):

You are looking for `fread()`.

`fgets()` keeps reading until length-1, newline or EOF.

You are probably getting a 0xa (10, \n) byte.